# Create Levant Arabic Dates

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, calendar, arabic

The Levant date is a date format used primarily in Iraq, Syria, Jordan, Lebanon, and Palestine.

It is mostly used in websites, newspapers, magazines, books, literature, and official documents.

The basic structure of the Levant Date format is a standard date structure (day, month, year) as per the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) and the ISO 639.

However, the Levant Date itself is not covered in CLDR format.

As can be seen from the following image, the month in the Levant Date is structured differently from the standard Arabic "ar" dates in that the month consists of both the Gregorian Month and the Assyrian Month (شهور سريانية (آشورية) أو شهور رافدية) separated by a backslash "/" (i.e. a forward slash for an Arabic text).

[image]

#### Examples of the Levant Date:

**١ مارس/آذار** **١٩٤٥**

**١ مارس/آذار سنة** **١٩٤٥**

١ **مارس/آذار عام ١٩٤٥**

**غرة مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥**

**الأول من شهر مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥**

**الأول من شهر مارس/آذار عام ١٩٤٥**

**الأول من شهر مارس/آذار عام ١٩٤٥ ميلادي**

**الأول من شهر مارس/آذار سنة ١٩٤٥**

**الأول من شهر مارس/آذار سنة ١٩٤٥ ميلادية**

[image]

The Date formats in Javascript for the countries Iraq (ar-IQ), Syria (ar-SY), Jordan (ar-JO), Lebanon (ar-LB), and Palestine (ar-PS) provide for the output with the Assyrian Months only (كانون الثاني, شباط, آذار, نيسان, أيار, حزيران, تموز, آب, أيلول, تشرين الأول, تشرين الثاني, كانون الأول).

The Javascript function provided below is my method/attempt to create the Levant Date. Any other ways/alternatives are appreciated.

## Syntax:

#### dateLevantArabic(date [,options])

The function takes a date object and optional parameters and returns a string of the Levant Date.

## Parameters:

**date**: A valid date object.

**options**: An object with some or all of the following properties:

**style**: Output the date as a string with full string ordinals for the days.

"**full**": full string ordinals for the days.

other values (default): short standard output.

**Examples (default output):**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31));
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10));
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 31));

output:
٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني ١٩٢٠
١٠ فبراير/شباط ١٩٦٧
١ مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥
```

**Examples (full output style):**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {style: "full"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10), {style: "full"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 31), {style: "full"});

output:
الحادي والثلاثون من شهر يناير/كانون الثاني ١٩٢٠
العاشر من شهر فبراير/شباط ١٩٦٧
الأول من شهر مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥
```

**sana** : Option to add the word "سنة" or "عام" before year number. Possible values are:

"**f**" : add the word "سنة" (feminine) before year number.

"**m**" : add the word "عام" (masculine) before year number.

**Default**: none added.

*Note: Selection of "f" or "m" affects the {calendarName} option output (see below).*

**Examples (with {sana: "f"}):**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {sana: "f"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10), {sana: "f"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 31), {sana: "f"});

output:
٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني سنة ١٩٢٠
١٠ فبراير/شباط سنة ١٩٦٧
١ مارس/آذار سنة ١٩٤٥
```

**Examples (with {sana: "m"}):**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {sana: "m"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10), {sana: "m"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 31), {sana: "m"});

output:
٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني عام ١٩٢٠
١٠ فبراير/شباط عام ١٩٦٧
١ مارس/آذار عام ١٩٤٥
```

**gora** : A flag "y" to use the word "**غرة**" instead of "1", "١", or "الأول".

"**y**" : to use the word "غرة" instead of "1", "١", or "الأول" for day 1 of the month.

other values (default): Use "1", "١", or "الأول" for day 1 of the month.

**Examples:**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1));
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1),  {gora: "y"});

output:
١ مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥
غرة مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥
```

**num** : Numbering system. Possible values are:

"**arab**" (default) for digits in Eastern-Arabic Numbers (**٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩**).

"**latn**". for digits in Westerns-Arabic Numbers (**0123456789**).

**Examples:**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1)); // default Eastern-Arabic Numbers
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1),  {num: "latn"});

output:
١ مارس/آذار ١٩٤٥
1 مارس/آذار 1945 // note must be displayed in RTL text direction
```

**calendarName**: The representation of the year. This is similar to Javascript Intl.DateTimeFormat() "era". Possible values are:

"**long**"   (i.e. "ميلادية" or "ميلادي" *depending on the {sana} option above).*

"**short**"  (i.e. "م").

"**narrow**" (i.e. "م").

**Examples:**

```
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {calendarName: "long"});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {calendarName: "long", {sana: "m"}});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {calendarName: "long", {sana: "f"}});
dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31), {calendarName: "short", {sana: "f"}});

٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني ١٩٢٠ ميلادي       // long form
٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني عام ١٩٢٠ ميلادي    // long with option {sana: "m"}
٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني سنة ١٩٢٠ ميلادية    // long with option {sana: "f"}
٣١ يناير/كانون الثاني سنة ١٩٢٠ م       // short form with option {sana: "f"}
```

## function dateLevantArabic(date [, options])

```js
/*********************************************************************
* @function      : dateLevantArabic(date [, options])
* @purpose       : Converts Dates to Levant Arabic form with options
* @version       : 1.00
* @author        : Mohsen Alyafei
* @date          : 31 Jan 2022
* @Licence       : MIT
* @param         : {date} a date object
*                  [options] are:
*                  - style       : "full" for full ordinal string else short. Default short style.
*                  - sana        : flag "y" adds word "سنة" or "m" adds "عام" before year.
*                  - gora        : flag "y" to use the word "غرة" instead of "1" or "الأول". Default: "no".
*                  - num         : Numbering system "arab" or "latn". Default "arab".
*                  - calendarName: "long", "short" ,"narrow" used for era.
*                                  "long" corrects the ISO error in representation of the era
* @returns       : {string} The Date in Arabic ordinal.
**********************************************************************/
function dateLevantArabic(date,{style, gora, sana, num, calendarName}={}) {
  gora  ??= "";         // default no "غرة" for 1st day of month
  num   ??= "arab";     // default with Eatern-Arabic
  style ??= "";         // default short form
  sana  ??= "";         // default no "سنة" or "عام" before year

let locale= "ar-u-nu-" + num, // default locale
    day   = date.toLocaleDateString(locale, {day :'numeric'} ),
    year  = date.toLocaleDateString(locale, {year:'numeric'});
    gora  = (day==="1"||day==="١") && gora.toLowerCase() === "y";
if (calendarName) year = date.toLocaleDateString(locale,{year:'numeric', era:calendarName});
sana=sana.toLowerCase();
let result = (gora ? "غرة" : style === "full" ? daysToOrdinals(day) : day) +
             (style === "full" && !gora ?" من شهر" : "") + " " +
             date.toLocaleDateString("ar",{month:'long'}) + "/" +
             date.toLocaleDateString("ar-LB",{month:'long'}) + " " +
             (sana==="m" ? "عام " : sana === "f" ? "سنة ":"") + year;
if (calendarName === "long" && sana=="f") result = result.split(" ").slice(0,-1).join(" ") + " ميلادية";
return result;

function daysToOrdinals(day) {
let d      = day.replace(/[٠-٩]/g,d=>"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩".indexOf(d));
    unit   = (d %= 100) % 10,
    ordinal= "ال" + [,"أول","ثاني","ثالث","رابع","خامس","سادس","سابع","ثامن","تاسع","عاشر"][d==10?d:unit],
    hadi   = unit === 1 ? "الحادي" : ordinal;
return d<11 ? ordinal : d<20 ? hadi+ " عشر" :(unit ? hadi + " و" : "") + "ال" + [,,"عشر","ثلاث"][~~(d/10)] + "ون";
}
}





//=======================================================================
// Tests for the default output
//=======================================================================
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log("Default output");
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2001, 3, 22)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2012, 4, 9)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2021, 5, 9)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2020, 6, 15)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2019, 7, 14)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2022, 8, 11)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1985, 9, 21)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1988, 10, 8)));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1950, 11, 7)));
console.log("اليوم هو " + dateLevantArabic(new Date()));
//=======================================================================
// Tests with "غرة" and "full year name"
//=======================================================================
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log("with 'غرة' and 'full year name' with 'عام'");
console.log("-".repeat(50));
let options={gora:"y", calendarName:"long", sana:"m"};
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2001, 3, 22),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2012, 4, 15),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2021, 5, 7),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2020, 6, 11),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2019, 7, 21),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2022, 8, 12),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1985, 9, 3),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1988, 10, 23),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1950, 11, 11),options));
console.log("اليوم هو " + dateLevantArabic(new Date(),options));

//=======================================================================
// Tests Ordinals with "غرة", and Latin digits
//=======================================================================
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log("Days ordinals with 'غرة', 'full year name' and Latin digits");
console.log("-".repeat(50));
options={style:"full", gora:"y", num:"latn"};
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2001, 3, 22),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2012, 4, 15),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2021, 5, 7),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2020, 6, 11),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2019, 7, 21),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2022, 8, 12),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1985, 9, 3),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1988, 10, 23),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1950, 11, 11),options));
console.log("اليوم هو " + dateLevantArabic(new Date(),options));

//=======================================================================
// Tests Ordinals with "غرة", "full year name", Latin digits, and "سنة"
//=======================================================================
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log("Days ordinals with 'غرة', 'full year name', 'سنة' and Latin digits");
console.log("-".repeat(50));
options={style:"full",  sana:"f", gora:"y", calendarName:"long", num:"latn"};
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1920, 0, 31),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1967, 1, 10),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1945, 2, 1),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2001, 3, 22),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2012, 4, 15),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2021, 5, 7),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2020, 6, 11),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2019, 7, 21),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(2022, 8, 12),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1985, 9, 3),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1988, 10, 23),options));
console.log(dateLevantArabic(new Date(1950, 11, 11),options));
console.log("اليوم هو " + dateLevantArabic(new Date(),options));
```

Comment: Does the modern Assyrian calendar use the same calendar rules as gregorian calendar? Are only month names different in writing (i.e. different names)? I just see and speak about the modern usage of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assyrian_calendar

Comment: It is simply using the Assyrian month names to express the Gregorian months. Originally this was done by using the equivalent Assyrian name. e.g month 4 (April) is called Nīsān (Arabic: نيسان). However, later on, both the Gregorian Name and Assyrian Names are used separated by a backslash as this makes it more clear to other countries not familiar with the Assyrian names to express dates (in books and literature, magazine, now on the web too).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Well, I am not an JavaScript-expert. In Java however, it is relatively easy to fulfill what you want, either with `java.time`-API or with my library Time4J. Using those APIs, you would use the builder approach (enabling customized month names) and instruct it to use arabic-indic digits, too.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @piet.t I have written the question above in the body here it is again:"The Javascript function provided below is my method/attempt to create the Levant Date. Any other ways/alternatives are appreciated."

Comment: So if your code is already working this does not seem like a good fit for SO in the current form. Splitting it up in a question/self-answer would be a better fit for this site's format.

Comment: May be you are right. However, I don't believe the solution I did is best fit.